# Methods for converting from HVZKP to ZKP: Precommitting the Initial Communication

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

In my studies, I have seen two common ways that an Honest Verifier Zero Knowledge Proof can be converted to a Zero Knowledge Proof.  Either make the proof non-interactive with Fiat-Shamir's Heuristic (thus removing the Verifier) or make the Verifier commit the challenge beforehand.

Wouldn't it also be secure for the Prover to commit his initial communications in a Pedersen Commitment?  The protocol would look like this:

1. The Prover calculates the initial communications
2. The Prover commits the initial communications and sends the commitment(s) to the Verifier.
3. The Verifier sends a challenge.
4. The Prover calculates the response.
5. The Prover sends the response and the information to open the commitment(s) to the Verifier.
6. If the transcript is valid and the initial communication matches the commitment(s), the Verifier accepts.

If my reasoning is valid, this would make the Zero Knowledge Proofs parallelizable without worrying about any meaningful interdependencies.  The commitments that would be used are perfectly hiding, and thus reveal nothing about the contents, meaning the Verifier has no real information about this proof until his inputs are completed.  This means the Verifier can't use information from ZKP 1 on ZKP 2's challenge and use that response for part of ZKP 1's challenge, which, as far as I understand, is a problem in parallel composition of Zero Knowledge Proofs.

The downside is the initial communications can be large and it could cost a lot of exponentiations and communications to commit them all in Pedersen Commitment and send them, but you may be able to commit using a hashing function instead, but these aren't perfectly hiding.

Comment: You need a trapdoor commitment to make the simulation work, but then this strategy works out. It is discussed in "Efficient Concurrent Zero-Knowledge in the Auxiliary String Model" by Ivan Damgard (Eurocrypt 2000).

Comment: So this works as long as the Simulator (replacing the Prover) knows the DLOG between the generators in the commitment and can thus "cheat" on the commitment and have any initial comm he wants.  Then, the Simulator (replacing the Verifier) can just send two challenges like in HVZKP proof.

Comment: Exactly, then you have a trapdoor commitment.

Comment: One thing I am not clear on.  Does the simulator automatically know the trapdoor, or does it have to be extracted from the adversary?

Comment: You work in a common reference string (auxiliary string) model. There the simulator knows the trapdoor. But in the real protocol it is set up by a trusted party and so the trapdoor is not known.

Comment: I don't think I fully understand why you need to work in a common reference string model to know the trapdoor.  The goal of the simulator is to create a computationally indistinguishable transcript.  If he knows the trapdoor automatically, he can open the commitment in any way he wants and the adversary can not the difference.  Simulators already have mystical powers that are outside the realm of reality, like rewinding and consulting the trusted party.   I don't see the harm in the simulator knowing how to open the commitment in any way he sees fit.

Comment: Is the common reference string model designed to accommodate the simulator without the DLOG just being handed to him and without the simulator having to solve for a discrete log?

Comment: What happens if the real prover knows the trapdoor?

Comment: The prover can cheat if he knows the trapdoor.  However, what happens if the real prover gains the ability to rewind the verifier?   What happens if the real prover can set and know the verifier's random tape?  Simulators already have the power to do things that real provers can't.

Comment: How will you guarantee the prover does not know the trapdoor without a common reference string (trusted setup)? Who would set up the commitment parameters? Regarding the remaining questions. That are already quite a lot of questions which you might ask in new questions?